# Notebook created in cloud has odd errors in Mathematica 10.3.1

Tags: wolfram-cloud, compatibility

I've downloaded a notebook from develop.wolframcloud.com and opened it in 10.3.1 (running on Win 10).  When I evaluate some cells I get syntax errors along the lines of...

```
Syntax::sntxf: "\"Clear[\" cannot be followed by \"riskVariance"
```

And certain characters are highlighted in yellow, most often parentheses () or square brackets [] and commas but sometimes larger items, say a whole function LHS.  I wonder if this is caused by some weird font incompatibility.

Additionally all the cells that I have created are on inspection in StandardForm and attempts to convert them to InputForm does not seem to achieve anything, they stay resolutely in InputForm.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could create a minimal notebook that shows these errors and include a screenshot of it opened on your desktop.

Comment: Note that the highlighting I mention occurs after evaluation..

Comment: The code in your screenshot enters just fine on my desktop _Mathematica_ version 10.3.1. You could just copy and paste it into a fresh notebook. Or, construct a minimal example of the problem: In the cloud create a simple notebook with a single cell like `1+1`, download, and test on your desktop.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock Certainly no problem with retyping the code into the desktop application or indeed your suggestion of copying it and pasting it into a new notebook though it is necessary to copy as Input Text for this to work and it can only be done cell-by-cell. However I'm sure the intention is that a notebook created in the cloud is compatible with the desktop application so I feel my complaint/bug report is justified.

Comment: A minimal notebook exhibiting this problem and explicit instructions for recreating it would be very helpful.